# Disable menu dismiss on backdrop press - react-native-popup-menu

Tags: react-native, react-native-popup-menu

I want to disable menu dismiss on backdrop press in react-native-popup-menu.

Comment: Or maybe disable the backdrop itself ?

Comment: maybe with https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu/blob/master/examples/StylingExample.js#L119